# Hyperledger Fabric: Do I need to install Go if I am going to write chaincode in nodejs?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

[This](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/prereqs.html) page says:

> Hyperledger Fabric uses the Go Programming Language for many of its
>   components.
>
> Go version 1.11.x is required.

but if I am going to be writing chaincode in nodejs, do I still need to install Go? If yes, why?

Comment: No you don't need GoLang if you plan to write chaincode in node.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR: You do not need to install Go if you are going to write chaincode in NodeJs. In fact, you can get away without installing Go even if you are writing chaincode in Go. This is because Go will be implicitly installed on the docker containers whether you like it or not.

To my surprise, I was able to run the fabcar sample described [here](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.3/write_first_app.html) (with language set to Go) without any issues on a machine that as far as I know does not even have Go installed.

So how is this possible? It looks like Go is built into the relevant docker images in [docker-compose.yml](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/release-1.3/basic-network/docker-compose.yml):

- hyperledger/fabric-ca
- hyperledger/fabric-orderer
- hyperledger/fabric-peer
- hyperledger/fabric-couchdb
- hyperledger/fabric-tools

As can be seen below, Go will be installed and available on the containers at `/opt/go` even if one did not explicitly install Go as part of hyperledger startup.

```
siddjain@goldenrwr-ca0:~/fabric-samples-v13/fabcar$ docker exec -it 76537088e078 bash
root@76537088e078:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer# ls /opt/go
AUTHORS          LICENSE    VERSION  blog         lib   robots.txt
CONTRIBUTING.md  PATENTS    api      doc          misc  src
CONTRIBUTORS     README.md  bin      favicon.ico  pkg   test
root@76537088e078:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer# ls /opt/go/bin
go  godoc  gofmt
```